# Facebook "Your account is temporarily locked" message help request

Tags: facebook

Yesterday I started getting the above error message when logging into FB and it directs me to a page to do a security scan (https://www.facebook.com/checkpoint/) At this page I get a message saying "Scan and Uninstall" and "Initializing. Please wait." And wait I do... Refreshing the page doesn't seem to help. Tried it from IE versions 8 and 10 as well as Firefox 17.

I highly doubt it is a virus on my computer as I have tried from four different computers, all with anti-virus/anti-malware installed. I have tried the FB to request an unblock of my account but it just comes back and says my account isn't blocked.

Ideas or suggestions?

Comment: Run a full scan with an anti-virus capable of doing very deep scans. (Think root virus) although I can't say what it might be.

Comment: Did... With different software. Resolved though, answering it below

Answer (score 4):

Okay, finally got it working again. What I had to do was keep refreshing the page every couple of minutes. FB logged me off at one point, logged back in, got to the same point again, refreshed page, then it finally got me to the news feed page.

So something to try if anyone else ever gets this situation.